# Can I corrupt my OS via incorrect usage of pointer assignments & value changes?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, bitcoin, corruption

As the title suggests, I'm new to C++ and practicing many different programs on Code::Blocks IDE. I thought about this today and can't seem to get an accurate answer on it. Can I unintentionally corrupt data on my OS with improper use of pointers? With a little more detail, will:

```
char *p ; //creating uninitialized pointer with a random address; 
          //let's assume it's the address to a variable within a valid file?
*p = 'G' ;

//or

int *p ; 
*p = 2 ;
```

Can doing this in my IDE/compiler files potentially corrupt certain data such as:

1. Operating Systems files - Maybe core operating system files and a value change from 1 ---> 2 could result in physical damage to an external device.

   AND/OR
2. Unopened random files on the C: drive  -  Say for example an important file that has been 256 bit encrypted; a change in a single value would make decrypting the document near impossible and thus result in a completely corrupted and unrecoverable important document. I wouldn't be aware of this corruption until months down the line as I try to open the file but receive an error message during decryption.

   AND/OR
3. Open programs utilizing temp memory - Say for example I'm currently running a cold-storage Bitcoin wallet program (a crappy one) and as a hypothetical the program has open a dynamically allocated file that's encrypted. This file holds the backup key verification file needed to access $100k in cold-storage bitcoin; a change of character within the file will permanently corrupt the file and basically result in a loss of recovery key backup data. So if I ever forget my bitcoin wallet password, attempting to use the recovery feature would fail and result in a permanent loss of a down payment on a nice house.

So these are some examples and I'm wondering if any of them are possible simply by messing around with pointers, trying to learn C++. I don't want to accidentally cause any of the above scenarios now or in the future (maybe working on a bigger project where the above scenarios would spell disaster), so please let me know if any of these scenarios are possible (albeit a very low probability of happening, but still possible maybe). Also would you please be kind to explain the dynamics of preventing the above scenarios if it's possible to corrupt data within the OS using invalid pointers, expanding memory leaks, ect.

Comment: Not leaving variables uninitialized is a good way to avoid any kind of problem. Also using containers and smart pointers instead of "raw" pointers

Comment: Probably not: the CPU itself will prevent you from accessing memory locations that do not belong to your process

Comment: In theory yes, since your code **could** run in a privileged scope (e.g., the kernel), but since you're not experimenting with privileged processes (I hope), you've got little to worry about.

Comment: @StephenNewell So you're saying that it is possible if I'm running .exe files with admin privileges? Sheds a whole new paradigm on the fragility of electronic components! Under that thought process, I wonder what would happen if a never ending loop created millions of uninitialized variables and assigned random values to them.

Comment: @MrSnowGlobe, as for the second question: you'd run out of memory. Or the OS would kill your process because it would be allocating too much stack memory.

Comment: @MrSnowGlobe - An admin privilege by itself wouldn't cause a problem.  You'd really need kernel privileges to do anything actually dangerous.

Comment: Yeah, you would actually get, in fact you should actually, get the famous `SIGSEGV`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A properly designed modern OS should be designed so that you cannot corrupt the OS by running a program you wrote. Note the *should*; look at the [CVE list](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/) for many examples where that was not the case.

The threat model of most OSes you might do development on does not protect your personal files against a program you run. See [XKCD 1200](https://xkcd.com/1200/). However, you can take precautions, such as:

- Running the program as a separate user ID
- or running the program in a Virtual Machine
- or running the program in a `chroot` environment
- or running the program while Mandatory Access Control is in effect, that prevents the program from writing to files outside a designated directory or opening network sockets (such as SELinux)
- and by properly understanding the program and avoiding errors such as this one

The risk is also mitigated by the following considerations:

- An uninitialized pointer is likely to be zero, hence null, and thus cause a segmentation fault when you use it; or if set to a "random" value, likely to point to unmapped memory, with the same result
- Even if you did change the argument for a subsequent `std::fstream::open` (or `open` from POSIX, or `fopen` from the C stdio API, or some other similar OS-specific function), it's unlikely you would actually change it to something that actually matches the name of a file some other program uses. Much more likely to either introduce a garbage-byte in the filename, or truncate it outright; unless your program is already doing something like "enumerate all files under my home directory, and open each one".

Incidentally, the code you give to set a "random" bit of memory to something "random" is likely to be far from "random" in a lot of cases. It might be the same value every time the program is run, for example. Some better (although C, not C++) alternatives...

```
   // #1
   char *p = rand();
   *p = rand();

   // #2
   FILE * randomDevice = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
   char *p;
   fread(&p, sizeof(char *), 1, randomDevice);
   fread( p, sizeof(char),   1, randomDevice);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the insight! Extremely helpful

Answer (score 4):

> Can I corrupt my OS via incorrect usage of pointer assignments & value changes?

Most likely not.

In modern desktop OSes and server OSes, the memory space used by processes is virtual. Accessing invalid memory causes undefined behavior but that does not allow the process to change files/memory that it does not have access to.

You could corrupt the OS if:

1. You run the program with root/admininstrative privileges, and
2. You modify/delete files that are necessary for the OS to run properly.

I am unable to comment on what could happen on platforms that don't use virtual memory for processes from lack of experience.